# How to dynamically define a class method which will refer to a local variable outside?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, closures, class-method, local-variables

```
class C
end

var = "I am a local var outside"

C.class_eval do
   def self.a_class_method
     puts var 
   end
end
```

I know, this is not correct, because the `def` created a new scope.
I also know that use `define_method` can create a instance method without creating a new scope, but my point is how to define a **class method**.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Class methods don't really exist in Ruby, they are just singleton methods of the class object. Singleton methods don't really exist, either, they are just ordinary instance methods of the object's singleton class.

Since you already know how to define instance methods (using `Module#define_method`), you already know everything you need to know. You just need to call `class_eval` on `C`'s singleton class instead of `C` itself:

```
(class << C; self end).class_eval do
  define_method(:a_class_method) do
    puts var 
  end
end
```

Current versions of Ruby have a `singleton_class` method to make that easier:

```
C.singleton_class.class_eval do
  define_method(:a_class_method) do
    puts var 
  end
end
```

But actually, current versions of Ruby also have `Module#define_singleton_method`, so, in this particular case, that is unnecessary:

```
C.define_singleton_method(:a_class_method) do
  puts var 
end
```

Comment: Great answer. Could you share links to ruby's documentation on class methods meta-programming? thanks

Comment: @mattgathu: There are no class methods in Ruby. There is only one kind of methods: instance methods.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a singleton method that takes parameters. How do I do it?

Comment: @mattgathu: There is no such thing as a singleton method in Ruby. A singleton method is just a normal instance method defined in a singleton class. You define a singleton method with parameters in exactly the same way as you define an instance method with parameters, because there are only instance methods. Singleton methods and class methods are nothing special, because *they don't exist*.

Comment: Great explanation! I would upvote multiple times if I could XD

Answer (score 1):

you can do it simply this way

```
class << C
  define_method(:a_class_method) do
     # do something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C.instance_eval do
  def class_method
    "This is class method"
  end
end
```

**instance_eval**: defines singleton methods on the object (which results in class methods when it's called on class object).

**class_eval**: defines regular instance methods