# ActiveRecord: How to include another model based on Enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, rails-activerecord

Have a Post Model with an Enum

```
// Post.rb

enum category: {
   job: 'job',
   conference: 'conference'
}
```

and an Org has and belongs to many Posts (via join table)

`Org.includes(:posts).where(category: Post.categories[:job])`

appears that its trying to call category on Org. Is there a way to write this to only
return the Org with included post, where the post has an enum of string 'job'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** use

```
Org.includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: :job})
```

*The longer answer...*

I guess it's worth noting that your question doesn't really have anything to do with `enums`. Nor does it have to do with "including another model". What you're really trying to do is [Specify Conditions on the Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) which you can read more about in the [Active Record Query Interface guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

The issues is that you've malformed your ActiveRecord Query:

```
Org.includes(:posts).where(category: Post.categories[:job])
```

The essential form of what you currently have is:

```
Model.where(attribute: 'value')
```

The:

```
.includes(:joined_models)
```

...bit doesn't change the essential form. And so, `ActiveRecord` will return all `Model` records where `attribute` has `value`. Or, in your case, all `Org` models where `category` is `job`.

But, that's not what you want. You want all `Orgs` that have `Posts` where the `Post` `category` is `job`. (Or, I suppose, "all Orgs with job posts.")

Which is where the `.includes(:joined_models)` bit comes in: it lets you specify conditions on `joined_models`, which in it's essential form looks like:

```
Model.includes(:joined_models).where(joined_models: {attribute: 'value'})
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, in your case:

```
Org.includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: Post.categories[:job]})
```

Or, as mu says in the comments:

```
Org.includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: :job})
```

Now, I don't know what context you're in, but wherever you are, that above code requires that your context knows a lot about `Org` and how it relates to `Post` and the attributes of `Post` which in general is not great. So, I suggest you add a method to `Org` which allows you to decouple the knowledge of `Org` in your context:

```
class Org < ApplicationRecord 

  class << self

    def with_job_posts
      includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: :job}})
    end

  end

end
```

And now you can simply do:

```
Org.with_job_posts
```

...and get back "all Orgs with job posts". And your context needs to know a lot less about `Post` and its attributes.

`Post` also has a category of `conference`. So, you could do:

```
class Org < ApplicationRecord 

  class << self

    def with_job_posts
      includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: :job}})
    end

    def with_conference_posts
      includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: :conference}})
    end

  end

end
```

But, if your `Post` `categories` start to grow, that will become tedious. So, instead do:

```
class Org < ApplicationRecord 

  Post.categories.each do |post_category|
    define_singleton_method("#{post_category}"_posts) do 
      includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: post_category.to_sym})
    end
  end

end
```

And now you'll have any number of methods like:

```
Org.with_job_posts
Org.with_conference_posts
Org.with_some_other_type_of_posts
```

Super! Check out [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487403/how-to-dynamically-define-a-class-method-which-will-refer-to-a-local-variable-ou) for more info from [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag).

BTW, that looks like a potentially unusual way to use `enum`. In the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), it says:

> Finally, it's also possible to explicitly map the relation between attribute and database integer with a hash:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { active: 0, archived: 1 }
end
```

I always figured a mapped enum was meant to use integers as the values, not strings. Interesting.

Comment: You should be able to go with `Org.includes(:posts).where(posts: {category: :job})`, no? And I often use strings with enums, makes things a lot easier to understand outside ActiveRecord.

Comment: @muistooshort - Absolutely. I stuck with the way the OP had it "just because". If it's really to be hard coded, your way is the right way. I'll have to think on that bit about using strings instead of integers. It never occurred to me. Perhaps an artifact that I don't ever live outside ActiveRecord.

Comment: I live outside AR all the time and often access databases using multiple tools, hence my distaste for things like `serialize`, numbered enums, STI, and other "easy" things that tie you to AR.